# How to remove all space characters from this source code

Tags: c++, c

As this c/c++ code:

```
typedef const char* LPSTR;
```

I want to remove all space characters.

I find 2 ways to do that:

```
typedef/**/const/**/char*LPSTR; // 1

#define o(s) s
o(typedef)o(const)char*LPSTR; // 2
```

But I do not want make any new line and any comment.

So, is there 3rd way ?

Comment: Why would you ever want or need to do this?

Comment: Why for heaven's sake would you want to do this...?!

Comment: stupid interview questions for win

Comment: Replace the spaces with tabs?  Or with new lines?

Comment: I'm not sure why this is getting closed... It's a dumb requirement, but someone might come up with an interesting solution (I looked at trigraphs, but that didn't work - would have been cool though) I'm still interested if someone can provide an answer.

Comment: Pass the macro definition on the command line, usually something like `'-Do(s) s'`

Comment: Are you planning to compete with [these nutters](http://www.ioccc.org/years.html)? =)

Answer (score 9):

<del>Stupid</del> requirements call for <del>stupid</del> solutions:

```
typedefconstchar*LPSTR;
```

Comment: Why the downvote? I remove all spaces without newlines or comments...

Comment: +1, that's the only possible way... :)

Answer (score 1):

In some place where you *can* have spaces:

```
#define typedef_const_char_ptr_LPSTR typedef const char* LPSTR
```

If you can't include the file with the macro in it, I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. Either way, I suggest re-evaluating the design of whatever causes you to require to not have spaces.